# entity username is already taken

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have 2 classes listed below:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Arrayt> Arrayts { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Tsk> Tsks { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Arrayt> Arrayts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

And the class that represents the matrix, which may have multiple users.

```
namespace WebPlanerZ.Models
{
  public class Arrayt
  {
    public Arrayt() { }
    public Arrayt(ApplicationUser user, string name, DateTime start)
    {
        Users = new HashSet<ApplicationUser>();
        Users.Add(user);
        ...
    }

        ...

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tsk> Tsks { get; set; }
  }
}
```

In a method in the controller I want to add and delete users of a given matrix. `db.Arrays.Find(arrayId).Users.Add(added.Single())` throws an exception

> entity username is already taken

when I save changes to the database. Thank you for your help in advance.

```
public void UpdUsers(List<ApplicationUser> users, int arrayId)
{
        if (users != null && users.Count != 0)
        {
            var equalityComparer = new MyClassEqualityComparer();
            var deleted = db.Arrayts.Find(arrayId).Users.Except(users, equalityComparer).ToList();
            var added = users.Except(db.Arrayts.Find(arrayId).Users, equalityComparer).ToList();

            if (deleted.Count != 0)
                db.Arrayts.Find(arrayId).Users.Remove(deleted.Single());

            if (added.Count != 0)
                db.Arrayts.Find(arrayId).Users.Add(added.Single());

            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the _exact_ error message?

Comment: 'System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException' message: entity username is already taken

Comment: What does `MyClassEqualityComparer` do? You apparently add a user with a name that's already in the database. By the way, you query the users all the way from the database four times (!) in this little piece of code.

Comment: Comparer compares the user id and it works well. I know, I change these four db.Arrayt.Find ... for one request. How can I add users who have access to the array without adding them to collection in Arrayt class?